# Mount window network drive to linux in different domain

Tags: centos, mount, windows, cifs

I am trying to mount a network drive to my linux machine (centos 7). The network drive is running on window server 2012 r2. The network drive and the linux machine are in two different domain. I was able to map the drive from a Window PC (same domain as the linux machine).

```
mount -v -t cifs -o username=myusername,domain=mydomain.local //serverip/e /mnt/win/
```

But when I ran the above command, it give me the below errors.

```
mount error(22): Invalid argument

Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I already added read/write permission for the user in the network drive. I can ping to server and the remote domain. But that did not work, either. What am I missing?